# Can a Firebase Security Rule check if someone has specific access rights?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Can I use the keyword "in" to check if a user's authentication matches a Firebase security rule?

For example, I create a user token with:

```
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({ "uid": "1234", "access": [file1, file2, file3] });
```

I want to check if the user can access a particular file by setting the following security rule:

```
{
   "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": "file3 in auth.access"
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this works or is there a similar pattern for Firebase security. I want to issue each user unique security tokens that allows them to access certain files.

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing is a form of role-based security, which you can definitely build on Firebase.

This requires that you store the roles in your Firebase (and not just dynamically add them to the token):

```
users
    twitter:214
        files
            file1: true
            file2: true
    twitter:469
        files
            file2: true
```

Your rule would then be:

```
".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/files/file1').exists()"
```

Comment: Hey @DoanhDo, I just noticed that this question is left without an accepted answer. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work