# Firebase Security Rules Without Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I use Firebase to store real time status updates for an app.  I have my own authentication system for logging users in.  I would like to share the data I store on Firebase to vendors who use our API, but I want to make sure they have only read access to our data.

From what I've read, it seems like securing data by user must be done through Firebase's own authentication system.  Is there a way to do this without using their authentication system (maybe through a token system)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a system where a vendor calls one of my APIs (protected by my own internal authorization system) that returns a token that the user can use to authenticate with Firebase.

I use PHP and there is a token generator written by the Firebase team [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php).  Don't forget the [JWT PHP library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) this token generator relies on.

The token generator takes what is called a Firebase secret (you can find this in your particular Firebase instance page) passed into its class constructor and returns a random token based on this secret.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely generate Firebase tokens in your application code, with custom properties that may be subsequently used in the Firebase security rules.  Take a look at [Generating a Secure Token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-token-generation) in the Firebase docs.

Also see [Can a Firebase Security Rule check if someone has specific access rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27100663/3587167), where [@Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) offered a more comprehensive role-based approach.